# read tab delimited file in clojure

Tags: regex, parsing, clojure, formatting, string-formatting

How do I read a tab-delimited file using Clojure? There may be whitespaces in a line which do not correspond to a tab.

E.g.: transform

```
some field     another-field     a third field
```

into

```
["some field" "another-field" "a third field"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to do it by hand you could use a CSV library, e.g.:

https://github.com/clojure/data.csv

https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-csv

Then you'd be on the save side if your requirements change (e.g. you want to allow spaces in values, the delimiter changes, you want quoting, ...) since you could easily adapt. However, directly splitting single lines works, too:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io]
         '[clojure.string :as string])

(with-open [rd (io/reader (io/file "/path/to/file"))]
  (->> (line-seq rd)
       (map #(.split ^String % "\t"))
       (mapv vec)))
```

Still, I'd go with a library if I were you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [data.csv](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv) Contrib library:

```
;; in your :dependencies
[org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.2"]

;; at the REPL
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv])

(csv/read-csv
  (java.io.StringReader. "some field\tanother-field\ta third field")
  :separator \tab)
;= (["some field" "another-field" "a third field"])
```

(Use something like `(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader f)] (vec (csv/read-csv rdr :separator \tab)))` to read data from the TSV file `f`.)